# Populate widgets from a cursor in onLoadFinished()

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I want to know how to use the `CursorLoader` to populate the widgets on a screen. All the examples online are only for using an adapter and this works great. What I need is a reliable way to update the views in my screen from a Cursor and on the UI thread and without sometimes crashing because of `StaleDataException` or the cursor being deactivated all of a sudden. Here is my current approach but I still receive some crash reports from users.

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {
        CursorLoader loader = null;

        switch (id) {
            case LOADER_ID_DATA:
                loader = new CursorLoader(...);
                break;
        }

        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor cursor) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getActivity() == null)
                    return;

                updateView(cursor);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    }
```

One solution would be to retrieve all the cursor fields directly inside onLoadFinished and pass them all to the handler to populate the widgets on the UI thread. But this is ugly because I may have a lot of values in the cursor. I would love to find a reliable crash-free way of dealing with all this.

Comment: "One solution would be to retrieve all the cursor fields directly inside onLoadFinished and pass them all to the handler to populate the widgets on the UI thread" -- `onLoadFinished()` is called on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare As far as I know, onLoadFinished is not called on the main UI thread. If you look for example at android-protips_location source code written by Reto Meier, he uses a handler to populate the widgets with the values. And his comment above onLoadFinished() is that he schedules an update on the main application thread.

Comment: Quote from Reto Meier: "Note that onLoadFinished is not synchronized to the main application thread, so I'm extracting the Cursor values on the same thread as the Cursor was loaded, before posting a new Runnable to the UI thread that assigns those new values to the UI elements"

Comment: The documentation examples (e.g., calling `swapCursor()` on a `CursorAdapter`) require it to be called on the main application thread. I have written projects that use `Loader` and can update the UI directly from `onLoadFinished()`, such as: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Loaders/ConstantsLoader. And, the documentation explicitly states "Subclasses of Loader (such as AsyncTaskLoader) will often perform their work in a separate thread, but when delivering their results this too should be done on the main thread."

Comment: Well I do remember getting crashes for not updating the UI elements from the UI thread when I was setting them directly inside onLoadFinished(). But it may have been due to buggy versions of ACL. I will test this again to see if it works.

Comment: This is weird becuase in Reto's pro android 4 book he states the same thing - I have not seen in the Android documentation myself and have not had any issues interacting with the UI thread here...

Comment: This is very weird - if I run my app in debug mode and break in `onLoadFinished`, Eclipse tells me I am in the main thread so this conflicts with Reto's advice in his book???

Comment: @CommonsWare reto does say in his book that `onLoadFinished` is not synced with the main UI thread... although it seems obvious that it should be. Do you think this is a mistake on reto's end?

Comment: @AlexLockwood: As the accepted answer points out, the one-and-only concrete implementation of `Loader` in the Android SDK -- and anything else that inherits from `AsyncTaskLoader` -- calls `onLoadFinished()` on the main application thread. Reto is correct insofar as the documentation does not specifically say that `onLoadFinished()` is called on the main application thread. But the documentation almost *never* states for a given method when it is called on the main application thread, so that is not unusual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After asking on #android-dev `SimonVT` and `readme` helped me to get the bottom of this.

There is nothing that states that `onLoadFinished` will be called on the UI thread so in theory you should use a `Handler` like advised in Reto's book.  However, when using a `CursorLoader` (which is by far the most common use case) you can pretty much guarantee that `onLoadFinished` will be called in the UI thread.

Comment: The reason for the "pretty much" is that CursorLoader uses an AsyncTask to do its background work, which uses a static handler to post back, and ultimately call onLoadFinished. If you call LoaderManager.initLoader(...) from the main thread, the handler is guaranteed to be attached to the main thread as well. For this Handler not be attached to the main thread, you'd have to create a Thread with a Looper, and start the Loader from there.