# ListFragment: display dialog once Loader has finished

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursorloader

How can I show a DialogFragment once the loader has finished? When I do this inside the onLoadFinished() loader callback, I get an exception that I can't perform that action there. I suppose this is because I am attempting to display the dialog somewhere other than the UI thread (as ListFragment loaders run asynchronously). Is there some other callback or observer in the enclosing ListFragment that is triggered when the loader is finished?

Basically, once the list view is populated I want to check the list. If the list is empty, I want to display an informational dialog giving the user some idea of how to create items for the list.

The exception that displays when DialogFragment.show() is called inside onLoadFinished() is:

09-18 10:51:08.974  25310-25310/[pkg] E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action inside of onLoadFinished

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: I've added the exception to the post.

Comment: seems you are right. did you try runOnUiThread ?

Comment: I just tried runOnUiThread as described by curtisLoew, but I get the same exception.

Comment: ok,  then run your Runnable like this: new Handler().post(r)

Comment: This worked. Just to gain some understanding, it seems the problem wasn't that the dialog was being shown on a non-ui thread, but that is was being shown inside the onLoadFinished method (which, actually *may* be invoked by the UI thread)? Instantiating Handler in this way runs the provided Runnable on the same thread that invoked onLoadFinished, only outside of the method via a message queue? Can someone forge or update their post with this info so I can select it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add fragments in onLoadFinished and other callbacks. It's related to [state loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html). Altough you can create the same package as DialogFragment from, extend it and ovveride show method. But you better not do it.

Answer (score 0):

From a [helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650966/905349):

> ...nothing that states that onLoadFinished will be called on the UI thread so in theory you should use a Handler like advised in Reto's book...

Considering this, the following should work:

```
 @Override
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             // Show your dialog here.
         }
     });
 }
```

assuming your listener is implemented in an Activity. Otherwise, use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).